# Where should the stellar-core root account seed be stored?

Tags: stellar-core, bridge-server

Should the root account seed from stellar-core be stored in the stellar-core config? After upgrading to the latest version of stellar-core, I'm not able to find the transactions related to the accounts that i had created with the previous version of stellar-core(v9.2.0). What should be done to maintain the account details when a node upgrade takes place?

Also should the root account seed be stored in bridge.cfg?If so why?